# Can I replace Halogen fixtures with these LED fixtures?

Tags: bathroom, led, dimmer-switch, bathroom-fixtures

I just moved into a new apartment, in the bathroom there are 6 lights in the ceiling and a dimmable switch next to the door.

I want to change the bulbs to LEDs, but these damn halogen bulbs are really really slim (G4 socket, 12v) and the LEDs that I bought are just too "fat" to fit in the housing.

So I thought I might as well change the whole housing and looking on ebay I see this
[3W 5W LED Ceiling light Warm/Cool White Cree Down light Recessed Spotlight Lamp](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3W-5W-LED-Ceiling-light-Warm-Cool-White-Cree-Down-light-Recessed-Spotlight-Lamp-/231261951964).

Will these work, or will they blow if I try connecting them to the present set?

Let me know if you need pictures of anything if you don't understand anything I wrote above.

Answer (score 2):

They Look similar.  Best bet is to check with Cree.  THey make fantastic LED products but without a spec sheet one couldn't know for sure on this.

Comment: one other thing to watch...some dimmers don't work with ALL dimmable LEDs...some require a dimmer rated for LEDs.  Lutron makes excellent dimmers for that that retail around 24 dollars.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Will check out the places you mentioned, I'm in Europe though and you mentioned dollars so I am not sure if the places you mentioned will support our 220v though...
Also wrote to a few of the ebay sellers...